# .htaccess Redirect all users to subfolder EXCEPT for IP

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I've tried countless combinations from forums, answers here on Stack Overflow, and blogs. I can't get this to work right.

I'd like to redirect all users to a subdirectory - "/const" - except for an IP that I deem worthy.

This is what I'm using so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.143\.253\.211
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/const/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/const/$1 [R=302,L]
```

And it redirects to the subfolder correctly, but it still redirects me, which is bad.

Little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule that you have is correct. When I add those to a blank htaccess file, I get redirected to `http://website.com/const/` as expected unless I change the first condition to my actual IP. Some things you should check:

1. Make sure you've flushed your browser's cache. Although 302 redirects shouldn't be cached in such a way, better to flush it just in case.
2. Make sure you are actually making a request from the expected IP (i.e. `^91\.143\.253\.211$`). You can test this by adding this rule to the top of your htaccess file:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^foo$ http://foo.bar/IP/%{REMOTE_ADDR} [L,R]
   ```

   And if you go to `http://website.com/foo` you should get redirected to a non-existing site but with your IP in the URL. If that IP doesn't match `91.143.253.211` then you need to change your condition to match the right IP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried emptying my cache/cookies to no avail. Your process for getting the correct IP seems overkill compared to Googling "ip", or going to "whatismyip.com". Is the IP I get from the RewriteRule different?

Comment: @GregariousJB It depends. If you happen to be on the same machine as your webserver, it's possible that the IP you get is localhost. If you webserver is on a LAN with your machine, it's possible you'd get an internal IP instead of the external one. Using the rule ensures you are seeing the exact IP which mod_rewrite will match against

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Skip flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) `[s]`. Here is an example with multiple IPs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^91\.143\.253\.211$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^8\.8\.8\.8$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^const [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /const/$1 [R=302,L]
```

**Note**

In the example before I had `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. This typically only works on server config files where the path to the filename itself is visible to the redirection script. Here I've changed it to `%{REQUEST_URI}` the part of the request that the browser can actually access.

Comment: @GregariousJB You must have another redirect somewhere. If there is no other code in the .htaccess file, check for other files. Also if you're using something like a blog it may have a redirect built in to reach the default folder.

Comment: Blank .htaccess accept for your code. No other .htaccess files.

Comment: @dcolumbus Can you check this on your system. I've updated it.