# Redirecting all users to maintenanace.html EXCEPT for my IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having a little trouble getting this working. I've searched tirelessly on here and other websites for the answer to this riddle but I've got nothing to show for it so far. Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
# Redirect users to /maintenance.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00.00.000.00$ # my ip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

This code doesn't work, no redirect. Removing the line with the IP does work except that's no good for me when I'm updating.

I assume there's other conflicting code in the htaccess somewhere that is playing havoc with the redirect so here's the full file

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  (C) 2005 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of Apache mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by
# your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Suppress mime type detection in browsers for unknown types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
##
# Disable Federated Learning of Cohorts (FLoC)
# If you uncomment the below directive you have to allow this technology in the 
# Global Configuration of Joomla. Read more about this in the Post-Installation 
# message in the backend.
##
# Header always set Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Disable inline JavaScript when directly opening SVG files or embedding them with the object-tag
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none'"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: This is the same problem as this guy here but his question never got an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223405/htaccess-redirect-all-users-to-subfolder-except-for-ip

Comment: "conflicting code in the htaccess somewhere" - but I don't see your "maintenance" redirect? Have you confirmed that the "your IP address" is the actual IP address that your server is seeing?

Comment: "but his question never got an answer" - but there would seem to be 2 answers to that question and one is accepted. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite the author never commented to acknowledge the issue was resolved and commented on the accepted answer as incorrect.

Comment: @MrWhite the maintenance redirect is pasted to the top of the htaccess file.

Comment: The author "accepted" that answer, after they made the comment. The comment doesn't state that it's "incorrect", just that point #1 in that answer did not help. It's probable that they were using the incorrect IP address, as stated in #2 on that answer. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted and there are no conflicts if you've placed the code at the top of the file. This points to the IP address you are using being incorrect. That is, not the IP address that your server is seeing. How have you validated the IP address? Are you using a proxy server/CDN/load balancer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess Redirect all users to subfolder EXCEPT for IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223405/htaccess-redirect-all-users-to-subfolder-except-for-ip)